# How to get the original string when using the func xml.marshall?

Tags: xml, go, sitemap

I am working on a sitemap for the website.And I don't want my url to be encoded.

How to do?
Is it necessary for urls in arrt in xml to be encoded?

go version:go 1.20

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    testXML()
}

type ElementTree struct {
    Href string `xml:"href,attr"`
}

func testXML() {
    e := ElementTree{
        Href: "https://www.test.com?a=1&b=2",
    }
    indent, err := xml.MarshalIndent(e, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    //<ElementTree href="https://www.test.com?a=1&amp;b=2"></ElementTree>
    fmt.Println(string(indent))
}
```

The output of the above code is：
`<ElementTree href="https://www.test.com?a=1&amp;b=2"></ElementTree>`

I hope to get this result: `<ElementTree href="https://www.test.com?a=1&b=2"></ElementTree>`

Comment: `<ElementTree href="https://www.test.com?a=1&b=2"></ElementTree>`  is not a valid XML. `&` has to be escaped. See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#syntax.